# Javascript or jquery confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i have this code :

```
<a href="#" class="removelink" title="<%=id%>"><button class="btn-icon btn-orange btn-cross"><span></span>Delete</button></a>
```

how could i add a confirmation dialog onclick with yes or no ?

thank you

Comment: The [content model of `<a>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) is "Transparent, but there must be no interactive content descendant." — you can't put a `<button>` there.

Comment: What is the code that actually gets executed and what is the empty span doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use native confirmation refer to Quentin's suggest otherwise have a look at [jquery-easy-confirm-dialog](http://projectshadowlight.org/jquery-easy-confirm-dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.confirm), it returns `true` or `false`, so you can just return it at the end of your event handler.

Comment: tried before posting didn't manage to make it work in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Leave?")
    if (answer){
        alert("Bye bye!")
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
    }
    else{
        alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
    }
}

<input type="button" onclick="confirmation()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery UI dialog control. VERY configurable and allows for a richer UI experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="removelink" title="<%=id%>">
<button class="btn-icon btn-orange btn-cross"><span></span>Delete</button></a>

$('a').button({
  click: function(event, ui) { 
  return confirm("Wanna leave ?");
}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way (without jquery), just change the `href`:

```
<a href="return javascript:confirm('Are you sure you want to delete');" class="removelink" title="<%=id%>">
<button class="btn-icon btn-orange btn-cross"><span></span>Delete</button>
</a>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: tried this before posting either i press cancel it delete the row in my case. thanks